# How to run desktop application with its Sql Server database on a machine that have not SQL server installed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string

I have already finished a desktop application using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008.
it's working perfectly on my machine (i have a SQL Server 2008 and 2005 ).
the database is local and unchangeable, 
i want this application to be run successfully on the machine that doesn't have SQL Server installed.

my Connection string is:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KBank.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Connection Timeout=300
```

I want to know the best and simplest way to make it.  thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a setup for your application that states SQL Server 2008 as a prerequisite. That's it.

For further help you would have to supply more information on how you use the database in your application and if you have a way to host a public sql server instance to which your application will connect.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KBank.mdf;User Instance=True` approach, then you have no choice but to install SQL Server **Express** (and no other edition!) locally on that / every machine that is supposed to use your application.

This approach is severly flawed in my opinion, and it limits your flexibility.

What I'd suggest is to use the *real* server approach: put your database onto a server (both on your development environment, and in production) and then you have the flexibility of having either a SQL Server instance on every user's machine (if that makes sense), or you can have a centralized server which the clients only connect to (no local database server installed).

Comment: please kindly post some resources about your suggestion if possible. Thanks

Comment: @Hassan: well, that's just the "normal" way of working with SQL Server - hard to say what kind of links would be useful - possibly [the SQL Server Developer Central ON MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa336270.aspx) as a starting point. Just avoid everything that deals with "user instance" or `AttachDbFileName=` ... put your database **on the server**, and talk to it from the client using the database's logical name on the server - you don't have to mess around with files on disk or anything like that...

Answer (score 2):

If the database is **"local and unchangeable"** how about the [compact edition](http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Introducing-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-%28Part-I%29.aspx)? That way your clients dont need to install a full sql server instance

Comment: i think that will be good and flexible solution, so i would be grateful if you gave me some Compact edition resources

Comment: It's free, just go and grab it at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

Comment: Hello Nick, i have tried it and i required a SQL Server compact on the users machines,

my connection string is 

Data Source=|DataDirectory|\KBank.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=knowledgebank;File Mode=shared read;Persist Security Info=False

and this is my query

 da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select info_id,info_text,cat_id from info " + cat, a.GetConnectionStringByName());
            SqlCeCommandBuilder br = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(da);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "em");

            Fill_Rb();

it worked on my pc and didn't work on the others machines

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nick. if you dont want to install SQL Server on the machine then SQL server compact edition would be one of the option. Syntax is pretty similar to SQL Server but it comes with limitations. like you can not have a stored procedures in compact edition and few more.

You might want to visit [SQL CE Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb895908.aspx) as a development resource.

Comment: thanks, i have used SQL Server Express Edition, then i used SQL Compact Edition then i used OLE MS-ACCESS database trying to make the application run without needing a third party component ... but it needs a server each time>> So i have used a SQLite version 3 .. and the problem solved

Comment: i faced some problems while trying to encrypt the SQLite but i solved it with a special encryption way that i have explored :D